# ESP32 Web Server periodic updating problem

Tags: html, webserver, wifi, esp32, arduino-esp8266

I am trying to publish some data I get from a embedded platform using UART transmission on to a web server using ESP32. This is the code I am using, I am using Arduino IDE. I am not quite familiar with HTML and have seen couple of examples where HTML is being used to update the server values by sending requests.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "ESPAsyncWebServer.h" 

AsyncWebServer server1(81); 

const char* ssid ="mywifi";
const char* password ="mywifipass";
char c;


String readuart() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    c = Serial.read();}  
  return String(c);
}

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password); 

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  server1.on("/test_data", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(200, "text/plain", readuart().c_str());
  });

  server1.begin();
  delay(100);
}

void loop() {

}
```

Following part of the code is publishing the first string I get but it stops there.

```
server1.on("/test_data", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
request->send(200, "text/plain", readuart().c_str());
  });
```

I want to update this one string periodically. How do I achieve that? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by *"want to update the string"* periodically? Do you mean you want to read the UART occasionally? Or you want the client (a web-browser or some program presumably) to ask the server for a new value? Or you want the server to contact the client and update the value occasionally?

Comment: Yes I want to read UART occasionally, and update the value on the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the page to reload itself every x seconds. You can change your response string to actual html and use the [meta refresh tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh). This happens on the client side (in the web browser).

```
server1.on("/test_data", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    String html = "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"30\"></head><body>"
         + readuart() + "</body></html>";
    request->send(200, "text/html", html.c_str());
});
```

Change the `30` to whatever timeout you want.

Another option would be to use client side JS.

Comment: Yes this i what I want to do but this code returns an error saying html is not captured.

Comment: When I put the html string inside the request->send function it works.

Comment: @Tea Yes, that should have been inside the lambda. Glad it helps.